# Disable email notification after change of password

Tags: plugins, php, email, notifications, pluggable

I want to disable the email notification if a user or an admin changes the password of a user.

After some Googling I came to find that I need to create a plugin and overwrite the `wp_password_change_notification` function found in `pluggable.php`.

This is the plugin and function:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Stop email change password
Description: Whatever
*/

if ( !function_exists( 'wp_password_change_notification' ) ) {
    function wp_password_change_notification() {}
}
?>
```

I uploaded the file to my plugin folder and activated it in my admin panel!

This needs to be done with a plugin because the `pluggable.php` file is loaded before the `functions.php` file.

Anyway it doesn't seem to work for me.

The user still receives the email.

I disabled all plugins and run the plugin on a clean install so no interference

The `WP_DEBUG` doesn't show any errors as well!

Can anybody tell me what to change or how to fix it any other way (except core modifications :-))

M.

Comment: I also struggled and tried creating/using a custom plugin, setting the WordPress-filters to false but nothing worked... Just today I stumbled upon the [Manage Notification E-mails plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/manage-notification-emails) and it works :)

Answer (score 36):

To disable user email notification, add this in a plugin or theme:

```
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

FYI [`wp_password_change_notification()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_password_change_notification/) controls admin email notification when a user changes their password

Answer (score 33):

To disable *Admin email notification* when a **user resets their own password**, create a Plugin (or [Must Use Plugin](https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-mu-plugins/)) using the following code snippet:

```
/**
 * Disable Admin Notification of User Password Change
 *
 * @see pluggable.php
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_password_change_notification' ) ) {
    function wp_password_change_notification( $user ) {
        return;
    }
}
```

This will stop the following email from being sent to the Administrator's Email in Settings > General:

> **From:** WordPress <wordpress@example.com>
>   **To:** admin@example.com
>   **Subject:** [WordPress] Password Changed
>
> Password changed for user: username

Suppressing this email notification has to handled with a plugin because `pluggable.php` is loaded earlier than a theme's `functions.php` file.

---

If you wish to instead disable *User email notification* that a **user has successfully changed their own password**, use the following filter placed in `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Disable User Notification of Password Change Confirmation
 */
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

This will suppress the following email from being sent:

> **From:** WordPress <wordpress@example.com>
>   **To:** username@example.com
>   **Subject:** [WordPress] Password Changed
>
> Hi username,
>
> This notice confirms that your password was changed on WordPress.
>
> If you did not change your password, please contact the Site Administrator at admin@example.com
>
> This email has been sent to username@example.com
>
> Regards,
>   All at WordPress
>   http://example.com/

Comment: There is a big mistake in this answer. The filter name is "send_password_change_email" not "send_email_change_email".

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/send_password_change_email

Comment: Noted. For reference, the two filters are related and can be used to disable user notification when an email _or_ password is changed by the user. The use case for either depends on what notification you want to suppress — email change or password change. For a clear picture, refer to the WordPress function `wp_update_user()` in `wp-includes/user.php`: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.5/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1795

Comment: hi, why would a this wp_password_change_notification function will run when there is already same name function?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Woocommerce:

Since WC 3.8.0 (November 2019), there is now a dedicated filter hook for this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_disable_password_change_notification', '__return_true');
```

Should suppress password change notifications.

Comment: that hook is only for when using woocommerce (woocommerce 3.8, not wordpress 3.8)

Comment: @Rafa Oops, yeah I have been doing so much WC + WP development that the lines have blurred for me. I've adjusted my answer thanks.

Comment: Beware that this will deactivate the **user-facing password reset mail** (see `/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-my-account.php`) and as such isn't related to the admin notifications...

Comment: This 'woocommerce_disable_password_change_notification' hook does indeed deactivate the **admin** "Password Changed" notification email that is triggered on WooCommerce sites. You'll notice in `/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-my-account.php` that it stops the `wp_password_change_notification()` function from being run and that function "Notifies the blog admin of a user changing password" [WordPress Developer Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_password_change_notification/)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, just clear the email address.

```
// Disable password change notification email.
add_filter('wp_password_change_notification_email', function ($wp_password_change_notification_email) {
    $wp_password_change_notification_email['to'] = '';
    return $wp_password_change_notification_email;
});
```

Comment: That's the best way to do it ***now***.  When the question was first asked, `wp_password_change_notification_email` did not exist (it was added in WP 4.9).

Answer (score 2):

Copy this following code and save as disable_email.php . Then place that file in "wp-content/plugins/" directory. And active from Admin Panel.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Stop email change password
Description: Whatever
*/

if (!function_exists('wp_password_change_notification')) {
    function wp_password_change_notification($user) {
        return;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ??? How is this different of what I did?

Comment: Have you made a plugin and placed your code on that ?

Comment: Yes that is what I thought I described. But I'll update the question if it wasn't clear!

Comment: try now. I updated the answer. It should work now !

Comment: Ha I just found and tried this but didn't work!

Comment: @Interactive You have to enable the plugin first. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress sends the notification by default when the user is updated with `wp_update_user()`.

Trying to overwrite this using filters, modifying `pluggable.php`, or overwriting with an empty function, doesn't work.

Instead use `wp_set_password( $password, $user_id )` when you don't want the notification e-mail to be triggered for users/admins on a password reset.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are wrong because those disable sending email when email is changed, not when password is changed.

Adding the code below into your functions.php file under your active theme (or alternatively in a plugin) should work. Worked for me for version 4.6.1

```
/**
 * Disable sending of the password change email
 */
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

See [official documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/send_password_change_email)

Comment: Not all other answers could be wrong and new answers are posted all the time.  You should be more specific in your answer when referring to "other" answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [wp_set_password()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password) instead of wp_update_user() to update the password as this won't trigger an email notification.

Answer (score 0):

Should this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/266006/73347 above still work to disable password reset emails to admins?

```
/**
 * Disable Admin Notification of User Password Change
 *
 * @see pluggable.php
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_password_change_notification' ) ) {
    function wp_password_change_notification( $user ) {
        return;
    }
}
```

I'm still receiving them :(
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*edit: this is to disable ***only*** the admin notifications when any other site user changes their password. I may have misread the question! Apologies* =]

The `wp_password_change_notification` function is responsible for this functionality inside WordPress that emails admins these user password change updates (as other posts have mentioned).

What I haven't seen here is that inside `./wp-includes/default-filters.php` ~line 499 (at the time of this writing) you'll see this function being added to the `after_password_reset` action.

A quick fix is then to simply remove it from the action list:

```php
remove_action( 'after_password_reset', 'wp_password_change_notification' );
```

You absolutely can rewrite/overwrite `wp_password_change_notification`, as it is one of the `pluggable.php` functions, but if you're looking to remove this functionality rather than update it, this might be a better option.

Comment: I will add that [after_password_reset](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_password_reset/) action is performed after the password reset procedure (login screen).  The sending of a password change notification as a result of profile editing can be controlled by the [send_password_change_email](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/send_password_change_email/) filter.

Comment: Wup! Your comment made me realize I might have misread this question. I was looking for a way to disable the admin notification when any site user changes their password. I'll edit to notate that quick - thanks @nmr