# Password changed

Tags: password

It comes every half hour a e-mail with „password changed“. What is this? How can i shut it out?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable email notification after change of password](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206353/disable-email-notification-after-change-of-password)

Comment: Probably just brute force attacks, but as @PantelD said you can disable the alert.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your question has been [asked again](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206353/disable-email-notification-after-change-of-password). Take a look at the answers there first.
2. You can also take a look at the solution to your problem described [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-lostchanged-password-emails-in-wordpress/). In sort it tells you to create a plugin and add this code in it:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wp_password_change_notification' ) ) {
    function wp_password_change_notification() {}
}
```

> Let us explain the code to you. WordPress has a built-in function wp_password_change_notification located in /wp-includes/pluggable.php file. That function is responsible for sending those email notifications when a user resets their password.

You can read more about the wp_password_change_notification() function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_password_change_notification/).

3. You could try using an existing plugin, like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/).